# Android gridView/listView get requested elements

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridview

I know the methods `getFirstVisiblePosition()` and `getLastVisiblePosition()` but these are only for the visible grid, if you check for the visibility for the element at `position` in the `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` you will see that it lies outside the range of visible elements(which makes perfect sense). What can I do to check if an element at a position is visible or has been requested by the gridView/listView. Something which returns true in the `getView(...)` method itself.

Why I am trying to do it:
I have a bunch of images that I am showing in a gridView. The images have to be fetched via the network(I am caching them once they have been downloaded), so I have  created an asyncTask to download the image and then show it in the corresponding grid. Since there might be a lot of images and the user might quickly scroll down, I want to insert some check in the `onPreExecute()` method which can tell me if it visible, otherwise I cancel the task for now.

```
if (!requested()) {
    this.cancel(true);
}
```

I am looking for appropriate code for `requested()`.

Really sorry for such a long question, finding it really difficult to explain. Any solutions or modifications to the question are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question. Do you want to know if, given a certain position, that view has ever been shown?

If that's what you want, you should have a boolean array in your list/grid adapter. In the getView function you set that position to true. Then you only have to implement a function to check if a certain position is true.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private boolean[] hasBeenSeen;

    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        hasBeenSeen[position] = true;

        ...
    }

    public boolean checkPosition(int position){
        return hasBeenSeen[position];
    }
}
```

The boolean array has to be initialized when you set the list/grid content.

Comment: No, what i want to know is if the view is currently visible or in the immediately following rows of the visible rows (for which getView() gets called while scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using View.getLocationOnScreen(); If the x and y positions are within your screen bounds then it should be on your screen. I'm not sure what this will return if it isn't on your screen, though.